# Python Django save image works in Manage.py shell but not when the viewing page

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have created a small function:

```
def generate_name_img(self, _name):
    fontPath = os.path.join( settings.BASE_DIR, "DejaVuSans.ttf" )
    sans30   = ImageFont.truetype ( fontPath, 30 )
    _path    = "static/css/images/names/"

    im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (200,50), "#ddd" )
    draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw ( im )
    draw.text ( (10,10), _name, font=sans30, fill="red" )

    _filename = "thename.jpg"
    im.save ( _path + _filename )

    return _filename
```

When I do `manage.py shell`, import the function and call it, it works. A .jpg file with the name is created. But when I view the page and let ajax call the script, it returns a 500 error that says `static/css/images/names/thename.jpg` does not exist. I hope someone could help me. I am running this script in a virtualenv. Everything works, the login, saving to the database, but I am having trouble creating the jpeg. Please tell me what I could be doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: try using absolute directories like "fontPath = os.path.join( settings.BASE_DIR, "DejaVuSans.ttf" )"

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I changed the _path to "_path = os.path.join( settings.BASE_DIR, "static/css/images/names/" )". But I'm still getting the same error. I also tried to comment out the "# sans30   = ImageFont.truetype ( fontPath, 30 )" and the "# draw.text ( (10,10), _name, font=sans30, fill="red" )". Manage.py Shell now gives me a blank image but when I try to view the page, it still gives me the "static/css/images/names/thename.jpg does not exist" error. If the reason for this error is my PIL setup, this should not also work in manage.py shell, am I right?

Comment: when you go to the directory, you see that the image is being created? (does not seem  PIL error)

Comment: your function runs? adds a print and check it on the console.

Comment: I added the print, and it does not print anything after the "im.save". And searching the log files for the print texts also made me see this error:

Comment: File "/home/testserver/gateway/util/printname.py", line 35, in generate_name_img
[Tue Dec 10 11:27:43 2013] [error]     im.save ( _path + _filename )
[Tue Dec 10 11:27:43 2013] [error]   File "/home/testserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1433, in save
[Tue Dec 10 11:27:43 2013] [error]     fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "wb")
[Tue Dec 10 11:27:43 2013] [error] IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/css/images/names/thename.jpg'

Comment: what do you get when you print the filename? -> "_path + _filename" ? (using os.path.join and absolute path)

Comment: Thanks Alexander. After checking _path, I found the problem my settings.BASE_DIR returns an empty string. When I changed my path to start from /home/ it worked. Now I just need to make the path, less hard coded. Although it's really odd that the original code works in the shell but not when I view the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your settings file, put something like:

```
from os.path import dirname, join, realpath

BASE_DIR = dirname(realpath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
```

Also is recommended to use the MEDIA directory instead of STATIC directory for files uploaded by users.